# Error while importing data into a SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to import data into a table and when I finish the wizard, I get these errors and I don't know why.. Any help?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

you have identity column defined in the destination table, go back to the previous import wizard page (based on your pic), go to `edit mapping`, check `allow identity insert`

Comment: The error message is  "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column" for **product_id**. This is Unlikely to be an identity column in a table called `orders`. More likely to be a FK violation.

Comment: @Martin Smith, I am not sure what is the schema of the table, I assume the identity column is the PK xD,

Comment: There is no mention of identity columns in the error message. Did you misread "integrity"?

Comment: @user7332622, what is your data source? and what is the destination table schema

Comment: @Martin Smith, the "integrity" could be the identity column integrity does not get kept when inserting the value directly to identity column

Comment: Or check whether there is **NULL** in your original data source while the destination table cannot accept **NULL**